# Object with optional data

Tags: c#, object, enums

How would you go about creating an object class where the parameters can change depending on a specific parameter?

As that might be a bit unclear I will just explain exactly what I'm trying to implement.

I have this object with a name and id.
Then I want it to contain a value. This value will always be a number, however I want different options for it.

I want a range option, where you have a maximum and minimum value it can be, and I want a preset option, that is a dictionary of preset values and strings that describe said values.

This is my current code:

```
class Register
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public byte ID { get; set; }
    public ValueType type { get; set; }  
    public byte MaxValue { get; set; }
    public byte MinValue { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<byte,string> Presets { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public ushort GetAddrAsShort()
    {
        return Convert.ToUInt16(Address, 16);
    }
}

enum ValueType
{
    Range,
    Preset
}
```

I basically just want the max and min value only to exist if type = Range, and the Presets to only exist if type = Preset. Is that possible?

Comment: Have you considered using inheritance for this? ie. `class RangeRegister : Register { public byte MaxValue { get; set; } public byte MinValue { get; set; } }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the defined shape of a type at runtime, unless you're using some pretty exotic APIs. So *mostly* what you want: isn't possible. What you *can* do is add logic to the setters so that certain combinations are invalid by throwing exceptions, but *that* makes things awkward in that order now matters, so honestly: it is best avoided.

If you're dealing with some kind of UI on this, you could just *not show the bits that shouldn't appear*, and in some cases (for example if you are using `PropertyGrid` etc to build a basic UI) you can use some of those same exotic APIs such as (such as `PropertyDescriptor`) to influence things at runtime - but: that's a pretty niche area, and probably much more work than simply doing the same through regular code (hiding and showing relevant controls).

One other approach is to use polymorphism, i.e.

```cs
abstract class Register
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public byte ID { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public abstract ValueType Type {get;}

    internal Register() {} // just to stop people adding their own unexpected subclasses
}
sealed class RangeRegister : Register
{
    public override ValueType Type => ValueType.Range;
    public byte MaxValue { get; set; }
    public byte MinValue { get; set; }
}
sealed class PresetRegister : Register
{
    public override ValueType Type => ValueType.Preset;
    public Dictionary<byte,string> Presets { get; } = new();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, im trying to us it in a propertygrid, however its in a collection in a collection, so its quite deep and i cant seem to figure out how to customize the collection editor. And to be honest it seems too complicated for where Im at.
I will see if i can make it work using polymorphism.